# gpg: "tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted" not a key ID: skipping error while installing new packages using apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, debian, gnupg, apt, debian-based

Unable to install new packages on Ubuntu 12.04, there is an error related to 'gpg'.
Executed 'Update Manager' (installed all updates) but still the problem persists, following is the error when I tried to install Oracl JDK 7

```
coder@ubuntu:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/java
[sudo] password for vikram: 
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~flexiondotorg/+archive/java
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.jE42eWWvmU --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted
gpg: "tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted" not a key ID: skipping
```

Comment: Same issue here trying to add https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa into 14.04

Comment: For this you can use `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`

Answer (score 1):

I take it you want to install Oracles Java - I think the easiest thing for you to do will be to do it directly from the binaries provided from them: http://codingforme.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/installing-oracle-java-jdk-6-or-7-on-ubuntu-12-04/